# MOSS 2007 - Site Unavailable?

Tags: 2007

We have a site collection that is no longer available.

If you click the a link (dropdown or navigation) and you get the spinning wheel of death.  No 403 or 503 error messages.

I tired navigating directly to the default.aspx.  Spinning wheel of death with no errors.

I tried directly navigating to a layout page or the web part maintenance page.  Spinning wheel of death with no errors.

I tried accessing via SPD.  Spinning wheel of death with no errors.

I went into CA and tried to access the Site Collection List, Quotas and Locks and ContentDbs settings.  Spinning wheel of death with no errors.

I checked the logs and not bells and whistle errors saying what is wrong.

The DBA checked SQL and there are no errors.

No other site collection is having an issue.  Content owner said he made minor code changes for presentation (?) to page.

No updates have been applied in between changes 2pm yesterday and first reported issue this morning.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Check the application pools and their accounts/permissions. Do IISRESET after any changes. Is the code change for a presentation in a feature? If so, I'd try to use powershell to disable that feature.

```
Disable-SPFeature –identity "PresentationFeature" -URL http://sitecollectionURL
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607879.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, the person responsible for the issue is clueless and no help.  We are going with restoring the DB.

Comment: Just a note, clueless users should not be extending SharePoint via code/designer! Lay down the wrath of Khan!

Comment: DB Srestore went with off with a small hitch, but was successful none th eless.  Oh, I know.  Unfortunately, the people at the top of the food chain give him special privileges despite repeateded issues.  The good thing, he is only f'ing his own site.

Answer (score 0):

more to Mike. If you are unable to disbale it. do you have backup then restore it before the deployment of features.
Detach and re-attach the content DB.